# Woocommerce: Change “add to cart” button color when something is already in the cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I want to change the color of the "add to cart" button when something is already in the cart.
I think that it is possible when a product is already in the cart to get a new class "added" or something else.

Could anyone help me with that and knows how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function woo_in_cart($product_id) {
    global $woocommerce;

    foreach($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $key => $val ) {
        $_product = $val['data'];

        if($product_id == $_product->id ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

To use it just pass the product id in a function it will return true if the item has been already in cart and will return false if item is not in the cart..

suppose the product id is "123"..

```
if(woo_in_cart(123)) {
  // Product is already in cart
  // add a custom class to cart button.
}
```

Comment: I want to change color of added product button, not change button text.

Comment: yes you can change the color of the add to cart button. just put the if condition in the class attribute of button and echo the class if it returns true. so if the product is added to cart or the product is already in the  cart the custom class will be added to button

Comment: Im not good at woocommerce, if condition should be use in loop add-to-cart or archive page?
could you write complete code?

Comment: i can not give you the full code here if you are looking for someone to write a code for you then i suggest you to go for freelance. i showed you how it should be done. and yes you have to use it in single-product page..